# Using hibernate CriteriaQuery for entity which has ID ref to another table entity

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, criteria, hibernate-criteria

I have a complex (for me) hibernate query I am trying to figure out and my head just can't get wrapped around how to do this.

I need to find all Device entities which have an EntityRegistration.userName =~ "foo".

Entity classes:

```
@Entity()
@Table
public class Device {
    @Basic()
    @Column(name = "HostName")
    private String hostName = null;
    @Basic()
    @Column(name = "RegistrationID")
    private String registrationID = null;
}
@Entity()
@Table
public class EntityRegistration {
    @Basic()
    @Column(name = "ID")
    private String iD = null;
    @Basic()
    @Column(name = "UserName")
    private String userName = null;
}
```

The Device.registrationID maps to EntityRegistration.iD.  I do not want to change the table to have EntityRegistration as a OneToMany reference.

Here's what I've tried based on similar queries where there is a OneToMany reference instead of a Basic type like in this case:

```
CriteriaBuilder builder = context.getBuilder();
Root<Device> root = context.getRoot();
Join<Device,EntityRegistration> joinReg = root.join("registrationID");
builder.lower(joinReg.get("id")), userName);
```

I understand why this code doesn't work, but I can't figure out how to write the query properly for this case where I have an ID reference.

Comment: Thanks for finding that but I'm afraid I don't understand how to apply that to my case.

Comment: Did you consider native query or it's not an option for you?

Comment: Native query is not an option for me

Answer (score 0):

Your code snippet is actually JPA Criteria, which is under JPA standard.

JPA standard does not offer a solution for join unrelated entities. See article from Hibernate expert: [Vlad Mihalcea](https://vladmihalcea.com/how-to-join-unrelated-entities-with-jpa-and-hibernate/)

It is doable ONLY using Hibernate QUERY:

```
TypedQuery<Device> q = em.createQuery(
"select d from Device d JOIN EntityRegistration e ON d.registrationID=e.id AND e.userName=?1", Device.class);
q.setParameter(1, "peter")
q.getResultList();
```

Comment: That looks interesting but how do I convert that into Criteria API based on my original post?  That's the part that keeps my head spinning so fast.

Comment: According my research I think, it is not possible. I did not find join() function taking entity class as parameter.